# Reinterpret casting IDXGISwapChain** Pointer to IUKnown** Pointer

Tags: c++, casting, directx

I'd like to do the following reinterpret_cast operation:

`IUnknown **ppIUnknown = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(ppSwapChain1);`, where ppSwapChain1 is of type `IDXGISwapChain1**.` I plan to later `QueryInterface` `IDXGISwapChain` or `IDXGISwapChain1` from `*ppIUnknown`;

IDXGISwapChain1 inherits from `IUnknown` through the following hierarchy.

`IDXGISwapChain1`
--> `IDXGISwapChain`
    --> `IDXGIDeviceSubObject`
        --> `IDXGIObject`
            --> `IUnknown`

Is the reinterpret_cast a legal and defined operation? I am uncertain and would appreciate feedback on this topic. I couldn't find an existing topic that covers this specific question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'cast up' which never requires a `reinterpret_cast` or a `dynamic_cast`. You can simply use `static_cast` since you are moving up the type hierarchy. You can also safely call a function that takes an `IUnknown*` directly with your `IDXGISwapChain` object without having to cast it at all because the public inheritance allows that.

```
auto *iunk = static_cast<IUnknown*>( swapChain1 );
```

Keep in mind that this does not actually increase the reference count on the underlying object. You either have to call `AddRef` or use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IUnknown*> iunk( swapChain1 );
```

It's 'casting down' that you have to be careful about.

For normal C++ pointers, you can use Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) and use `dynamic_cast` which will verify the types are in fact convertible at runtime, and handling the possible nullptr that comes back if the types aren't compatible. Or you would use `reinterpret_cast` if you just wanted to force the pointer to another type and it's up to you the programmer to ensure the results are always valid.

With COM, you use `QueryInterface` which is functionally the same as a `dynamic_cast` to see if a given COM object supports a particular interface. Or better yet, use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` and the `As` operator.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain1;
HRESULT hr = iunk.As( &swapChain1 );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    // swapChain1 is now a valid pointer to the COM object with another ref
}
```